# jquery $.get() returns [object,object]

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

I am trying to return some vale from controller and using these values in jquery.But jquery function return [object, object].

controller function:

```
public function skillsReturnJson() {
    $skilljson = Skill::find()->skill_name;
    return $skilljson;
}
```

jquery function:

```
function addNew() {
     $.get('skills_json', function(data){
           alert(data);
    },'json');
```

route to controller:

```
 Route::POST( 'skills_json', array( 'uses' => 'MyProfile@skillsReturnJson' ));
```

Comment: You need to pass a skill ID into the find method. For instance, to find skill with ID = 1: Skill::find(1)->skill_name;

Comment: `console.log` instead of `alert`, please : ))

Comment: the alert function won't return anything useful for a complex object.  Try using `console.log(data)` instead of `alert(data)` and check out something like chrome dev tools

Comment: `data` references to an object, so instead `alert(data)`, you probably want to access the array key values. Use `console.log(data)` to find out the key names.

Comment: console.dir(data) is the most apropiate debug dumper for visualizate Javascript's objects

Answer (score 1):

Try the Response object for a start and return an array of data.

```
public function skillsReturnJson() {
    $skilljson = Skill::find()->skill_name;
    return Response::json(['data', $skilljson->toArray()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `console.log(data)` in the place of `alert(data)` to see what the objects contain. Basically the data variable is an array of objects. When you check the console, you'll be able to see what properties those objects contain. For example: let's say each object contained a property of 'skill_name', you could access each objects 'skill_name' with `data[0].skill_name` and `data[1].skill_name` (because from your post it returned two results 0 for first object and 1 for the second).